# How to play a sound more than once on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, audio, audio-player

I am working on music player and I ran into some issues I needed help on.

```js
function play() {
    document.getElementById("embed").innerHTML="<embed src='sound/1.mp3' autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true>";
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <button class="btn blue" type="button" onclick="sound()">PLAY</button>
    <div id="embed"></div>
</form>
```

When the sound is done playing, is there a way to replay it?

Also, is there a way for PHP to list all the .mp3 files in one folder in that format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue 1-

Try to use the `<audio>` tag. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)

There you can set the "loop" attribute.

Issue 2-

```
$dir = '/path/to/dir/*.mp3';

foreach(glob($dir) as $mp3)
{
    $k = pathinfo($mp3);
    $m = $k['basename'];
    $v = explode(".",$k['basename']);
    echo "<li><a href='#' data-src='dir/".$m."'>".$v[0]."</a></li>";

}
```

Hope this helps.